# How do you install Xcode and the Command Line Tools on Yosemite?

Tags: xcode, osx-yosemite

I followed the instructions here:

http://quantgreeks.com/how-to-install-xcode-command-line-tools-in-osx-yosemite/

However, I didn't fit the exact requirements for that tutorial because I never installed Xcode before.  In addition, I had trouble figuring out how to download Xcode. I ended up at the App Store, where it said my Developer account had been suspended for security reasons--but I can log in fine in the Apple Developer area. I ended up here:

https://developer.apple.com/devcenter/mac/index.action

where I clicked on View all downloads, and then I downloaded the Xcode 6.2 dmg file.  Then I clicked on the dmg file, and the installer had me drag the Xcode icon onto a folder icon.

I followed the rest of the steps in the tutorial, and at the end of the tutorial, it says to test your install like this:

```
$ xcode-select -p
/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools
```

However, I get the output:

```
$ xcode-select -p
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer
```

I do have the following directory:

```
/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools
```

**My conclusions:**

1)  In tutorials, make sure you pay attention to the distinction between the phrases `the Full Xcode Package` and the `the Xcode Command Line Tools`.

2)  If you install the `Full Xcode Package`, and then you test the installation I think this might be the correct output:

```
$ xcode-select -p
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer
```

3)  If you install just the `Xcode Command Line Tools`, and then you test the installation, then this might be the correct output:

```
$ xcode-select -p
/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools
```

Comment: AFAIK you only need to open XCode. It will prompt you to install the command line tools.

Answer (score 4):

I follow [this link](http://railsapps.github.io/xcode-command-line-tools.html) to detect and install the Xcode command line tools.

Here is the main command it sounds like you need to follow after verifying the full Xcode package is installed.

```
xcode-select --install
```

Comment: Thanks for the link.  Based on those two tutorials, I'm going to add some conclusions to my question.

Answer (score -1):

I follow [this link](https://developer.apple.com/downloads/) to install the Xcode command line tools.

You can choose your command line tools depending on your OS X 
for example for me I have OS X 10.8.5 I go to command_line_tools_for_osx_mountain_lion_april_2014